# xcode 7 Gm seed and other Xcode 7 beta , LAContext.h error

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, xcode6, touch-id

i have on problem with **LocalAuthentication.Framework**

in Framework-> LocalAuthentication -> LAContext.h

```
- (void)evaluateAccessControl:(SecAccessControlRef)accessControl
                    operation:(LAAccessControlOperation)operation
              localizedReason:(NSString *)localizedReason
                        reply:(void(^)(BOOL success, NSError * __nullable error))reply
                        NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
```

i receving **SecAccessControlRef Expected a type**

and when i use  `#import <LocalAuthentication/LocalAuthentication.h>`

i receving **Could not build module 'LocalAuthentication'**

Answer (score 0):

This error also happened to me. The error I had was that I had a copy of Security.framework file in my project which was not the file that had to be into the SDK.
The problem was solved excluding the non original Security.framework file from the project and deleting it from the folder.